# Magento PHP Fatal error, website not working (frontend and admin)

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento site that I have been working on.

So recently I decided to install new update to a 1.9.1 version in magento however I disocvered later that the extensions I also want to download are not compatible with the newest version.

So I decided to delete the extension files I updated and upload the old extensions again within app/var/package

However this caused great error and now the frontend and admin of my website won't load.

I have an error log within my public_html and there is an error that display:

```
PHP Fatal error: class 'Mage_Admin_Helper_Data' not found in /home/company/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php on line 123
```

The line within:

```
  public function collectRoutes($configArea, $useRouterName)
{
    if ((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_USE_CUSTOM_ADMIN_PATH)) {
        $customUrl = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_CUSTOM_ADMIN_PATH);
        $xmlPath = Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_ADMINHTML_ROUTER_FRONTNAME;
        if ((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode($xmlPath) != $customUrl) {
            Mage::getConfig()->setNode($xmlPath, $customUrl, true);
        }
    }
    parent::collectRoutes($configArea, $useRouterName);
}
```

The line 123 being:

```
if ((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode($xmlPath) != $customUrl) {
```

Help will be must appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by rerunning the install from SSH

```
chmod +x mage

./mage mage-setup .

./mage config-set preferred_state stable

./mage sync

./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force

php shell/indexer.php reindexall

rm -rf downloader/.cache/ var/cache/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but even if it looks like the probem comes from Mage_Admin_Helper_Data, with xdebug, I found that the error came from Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Help_Mapping (for me at least)

Check [this page](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Version-Upgrades/After-upgrading-magento-1-9-2-1-to-1-9-3-7-this-error-appears/td-p/83793) for more information.

Comment: In fact, it was as simple as [this](http://blog.kupriyanov.com/2018/03/solved-fatal-error-class.html)

Answer (score -1):

I just got this same error. Let me know if you get it resolved.